# Symfony 2 MediaBundle file upload tutorial wanted, how to start?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new with Symfony and MediaBundle, can't find tutorial how to upload files to server using MediaBundle, only display. Video would be perfect. I'm using latest Symfony 2.5. I need simple file upload, without any Sonata Media Bundle, or I must use Sonata for upload?

Only official example I found:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/media/introduction.html#uploading-files

and no working code examples.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading, I use the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and use jQuery for my front end.  Uploading can be involved because you have to handle different interfaces on users and then also have a method to save files on your server.  This bundle allows you to use different front ends for the design and has sever nice events for handling different types of uploads.

I use the included oneup_uploader.pre_upload event to review the file that will be uploaded and use oneup_uploader.post_upload to have the file's name stored in a related entity so I can easily access it from a controller/service.  It has some decent examples but post any questions if you are stuck.  One of the most useful features for me is the [custom logic for uploads](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_logic.md).